# Rails Form - Error when deselecting on a collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, erb, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a bare bones rails form. I have minimal javascript for adding and removing the category fields. I don't want it to be fancy so a rails specific solution is what I'm looking for.

The form is for Posts with a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship to Categories.

```
<%= form.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "None", include_hidden: false}, {multiple: true} %>

<% @posts.categories.each do |category| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :categories, category do |c_subform| %>
        <div>
          <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
          <%= f.label :name, "Category name", class: 'form-label' %>
           <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
    <% if @posts.new_record? %>
      <div>
        <%= link_to "Remove Category", '#', class: "remove_fields", style: "color: red" %>
        <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Category", form, :categories %>
      </div>
    <% end %>          
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I added the ability to select multiple categories and there is another fieldset below allowing the user to create new categories. The issue is while editing a post, if I deselect one of the previously selected categories (in this case, the one with ID of 3), on save I get the error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find Category with ID=3 for Post with ID=23`.

I would love for the update action to just delete the posts_categories record connecting Post 23 and Category 3 without deleting Category 3.

I want to add that the form worked fine until I decided to add the multi-select functionality by making it checkboxes that could be deselected and also required the category names be unique.

Comment: I'm now realizing that it may have something to do the the "create new category" part of the form. On edit, the form loops through the post's categories and allows the user to edit the category names. Because of that, the form params have `category_ids: [2]` and also `categories_attributes: #<ActionController::Parameters {"0"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"2", "name"=>"Old Category"} permitted: true>, "1"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"3", "name"=>"New Category"} permitted: true>} permitted: true>`. Maybe the answer won't be so simple.

Comment: The answer here most likely doesn't have that much to do with Rails - rather its all down to whatever kind of crazy shenanigans you have going on in your app.  There is absolutely no way we can help you unless you give us the full picture. An simple select doesn't do anything on its own.

Comment: @max you're right, I have added the rest of the category code.

Comment: Well for starters you don't want `<% @posts.categories.each do |category| %>` as `fields_for` will loop through the association. It also looks like you're using nested attributes which isn't really needed or the best solution if you're letting the user define new categories with JS.